# Form action target PHP file gets downloaded instead of getting parsed

Tags: php, forms

The PHP file referred in action of form gets downloaded instead of parsed! Here is the bit of code that activates the event:

```
<form method="post" action="./php/signup.php">
```

Here is the PHP file:

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$first = $_POST["first"];
$last = $_POST["last"];
$passworda = $_POST["passworda"];
$passwordb = $_POST["passwordb"];
$emaila = $_POST["emaila"];
$emailb = $_POST["emailb"];
if ($passworda != $passwordb) {
        echo "Passwords do not match!";
} else {
        echo "Password Check Complete!";
}
if ($emaila != $emailb) {
        echo "E-Mails do not match";
} else {
        echo "E-Mail Check Complete!";
}
```

What could be the possible problem?

Comment: did you miss `<?php` at the beginning? Did you use IIS, and have not properly configured the `php-mime-type`? did you use `<?` and have php-short-open-tags disabled in php ini?

Comment: The fact that the PHP code is returned rather than being executed points to a configuration issue with your server. The fix will depend on which server software you are using (Apache, IIS, nginx, etc.). We'll need those details to properly answer the question.

Comment: Maybe this is a header issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dognose Yep, I missed `<?php` and `?>`. Thanks!